# Changing the value of an item in a for-of loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm learning some of the new tricks in ES6, and I quite like the for-of loop for arrays. One thing I'm having some trouble with is if I want to manipulate the current item's value inside the loop.

For example in ES5:

```
var myArr = [1,2,3];
for(var i = 0; i < myArr; i++){
    myArr[i] = "moo"
}
```

When using the for-of loop in ES6 if I change the value of the current item inside the loop it's not reflected in the array. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why not use `map`? You don't need to mutate the array, you can transform the data!

Comment: This isn't a `for of` loop.

Comment: `for of` is an additional way to iterate over arrays. It doesn't remove the old ones. Use it *when it's convenient*, that's all.

Comment: Note that there's what I assume is a typo in the question, you're missing `.length` in `i < myArr;`.

Comment: For next time, I recommend showing the construct you're asking about (in this case, `for-of`), to avoid having *lots* of people misread the question.

Comment: myArr.map(()=>"moo")

Comment: I'm aware of map, was just curious if there was a way to do it from within the for-of loop. Just wanted to know if I was missing something, no particular issue.

Comment: *"if I change the value of the current item inside the loop it's not reflected in the array"* How are you doing that? I guess you do something like `for (var item of arr) { item = 'moo'; }` ? That can't work for the same reason that `var foo = 42; var bar = foo; bar = 21;` doesn't change `foo` to `21`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you also need the index in an array iteration with a `for … of` loop, use the [`.entries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries):

```
const myArr = [1,2,3];
for (const [i, el] of myArr.entries()) {
    myArr[i] = "moo" + el;
}
```

If you're only interested in the indices and no values, you could iterate `myArr.keys()` instead.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine. I would suggest to add `keys` to the answer since it conforms the question.

Answer (score 4):

Not with `for-of`, no. You don't have the index of the item, and writing to your variable has no effect on the original array.

You could hack it:

```
let index = 0;
for (const v of myArr) {
    if (/*...some condition...*/) {
        myArr[index] = "moo";
    }
    ++index;
}
```

...and that works, because of the definition of the array iterator, but it's pretty verbose. In that case, `forEach` might be a better choice if you want to update the array in-place, or `map` if you're happy to create a new array, or a good old-fashioned `for` loop.

Gratuitous example of the above (also showing that it works with sparse arrays, because of the way the array iterator is defined):

```js
let myArr = [1,2,3];
myArr[10] = "sparse"; // Just to prove it works
console.log("before", myArr);
let index = 0;
for (const v of myArr) {
    if (v === "sparse") {
        myArr[index] = "moo";
    }
    ++index;
}
console.log("after", myArr);
```